# How much time will the script execution "sleep" for?

Tags: ros

My understanding is that the code will keep the execution at 5Hz by accounting for the time used by the work done during the execution. SO this program will sleep for a period of "5Hz"?

```
# Initialize node 
rospy.init_node('publish_velocity')

r = rospy.Rate(5)

r.sleep()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `r.sleep` will sleep for one duration of the interval you specified. So in your case, 5Hz, it will sleep for 200ms.